# .net remoting stops every 100 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

We have very strange problem, one of our applications is continually querying server by using .net remoting, and every 100 seconds the application stops querying for a short duration and then resumes the operation. The problem is on a client and not on the server because applications actually queries several servers in the same time and stops receiving data from all of them in the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen that behavior before and unfortunately it's a vague enough scenario I think you're going to have a hard time finding someone on this board who's encountered the problem.  It's likely specific to your application.

I think there are a few investigations you can do to help you narrow down the problem.

1. Determine whether it's the client or server that is actually stalling.  If you have problems determining this, try installing a packet filter and monitor the traffic to see who sent the last data.  You likely won't be able to read the binary data but at least you will get a sense of who is lagging behind.
2. Once you figure out whether it's the client or server causing the lag, attempt to debug into the application and get a breakpoint where the hang occurs.  This should give you enough details to help track down the problem.  Or at least ask a more defined question on SO.

Comment: Yes I know is vague but it's an old problem (3 years) and no body here was able to figure it out so I was interested to see if somebody else saw it. The problem is on a client and not on the server

Answer (score 3):

100 Seconds is a give away number as it's the default timeout for a webrequest in .Net.

I've seen in the past that the PSI (Project Server Interface within Microsoft Project) didn't override the timeout and so the default of 100 seconds was applied and would terminate anything talking to it for longer than that time.

Do you have access to all of the code and are you sure you have set timeouts where applicable so that any defaults are not being applied unbeknownst to you?

Comment: It's looks like some default but I talking about remoting request not a webrequest and did not found any such defaul in remoting

Answer (score 0):

How is the application coded to implement the continuous querying?  Is it in a continuous loop? or a loop with a Thread.Sleep?  or is it on a timer ?,

It would first be useful to determine if your system is executing this "trigger" in your code when you expect it to, or if it is, and the remoting server is not responding...  so, ...

if you cannot reproduce this issue in a development environment where you can debug it, then, if you can, I suggest you add code to this Loop to write out to a log file (or some other persistence mechanism) each time it "should" be examining whatever conditions it uses to decide whether to query the remoting server or not, and then review those logs when the problem reoccurs...

If you can do the same in your remoting server, to record when the server receives a remoting request, this would help as well...

... and oh yes, just a thought, (I don;t know how you have coded this... ) but if you are using a separate thread in client to issue the remoting request, and the channel is being registered, and unregistered on that separate thread,  make sure you are deconflicting the requests, cause you can't register the same port twice on the same machine at the same time... 
(although this should probably have raised an exception in your client if this was the issue)